# React native map-view not loading map

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was testing the new changes in my app on my android device and everything was ok, but when I turned on the internet so the google map could load nothing have changed. Is it some problem with my API key? I was using this code before and the map would always load normally.

```
<MapView
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  region={this.state.place.coordinates}
  ref={(c)=> this._map = c}
  showsUserLocation={true} >
    {this.getMarkers()}
</MapView>
```

[image]

Comment: This does look like an API key issue. Are you running your app in debug mode or release mode? Have you added your API key to both and is it restricted? Is your billing account in good standing? Please post your full code and any errors you may be getting too so that we can help from our side.

Comment: I had a commit on the github that have changed the api key, and made a pull not knowing about it. Thank you for making me realize my mistake.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the issue & happy to help! :)